# Combine severel collections into one?

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have the following code:

```
Object value = methodOutOfMyControl();        
Collection<LinkedHashSet<String>> values = ((Map) value).values();
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<String>();
for (LinkedHashSet<String> set : values) {
    strings.addAll(set);
}
```

Is there way to rewrite this code more laconic?

**P.S.** I use java 6

Comment: "P.S. I use java 6" Why?

Comment: If you have to stay on Java 6, then this code is ok.

Comment: @tobias_k Question to customer

Comment: You could use `Iterables.concat`, but this will only give you an Iterable... I don't think there is a cleaner solution using Guava. Of course, you could just write a helper-method, if you need to do this a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks nicer:

```
 Collection<LinkedHashSet<String>> values = ((Map) userPreferenceValue).values();
 Set<String> contraValues = Sets.newHashSet(Iterables.concat(values));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 6 I would recommend Guava's FluentIterable:

```
Object value = methodOutOfMyControl();
Collection<LinkedHashSet<String>> values = ((Map) value).values();

//transformAndConcat is similar to Java 8, Stream.flatMap
final ImmutableSet<String> set = FluentIterable.from(values)
      .transformAndConcat(Functions.identity()).toSet();
```

Or if you really want it in one line:

```
 final ImmutableSet<String> set = FluentIterable.from(
            ((Map<?, LinkedHashSet<String>>) this.methodOutOfMyControl()).values())
        .transformAndConcat(Functions.identity())
        .toSet();
```